# Finding the number of surfaces containing a curve given its parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

If there is a parametrized curve: $$r(t) = t^2\,i + ln(t)\,j + \frac{1}{t}\,k$$

then as I understand it, to find surfaces that contain the curve, you can solve for $t$ and find three equations, each missing one of the three variables, giving three equations for surfaces that contain the curve.

$$x = t^2\\y = ln(t)\\z = \frac{1}{t}$$

$$1)\,\,t = \frac{1}{z} \Rightarrow x = (\frac{1}{z})^2 = \frac{1}{z^2}$$
$$2)\,\,y = ln(t) \Rightarrow t = e^y \Rightarrow x = e^{2y}$$
$$3)\,\,z = \frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{e^y}$$

Above are three surfaces that contain the curve; but are there infinitely many surfaces that contain this curve? Could you not translate that surface infinitely many times and still have the curve lie on the surface?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that if you have some surface containing the curve, you can deform it as you want (except "on" the curve) in infinitely many ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are infinitely many surfaces indeed. An easy way to generate them is to take any three functions with the property $f(0)=g(0)=h(0)=0$. Then the surface
$$
r(t,s) = (t^2 + f(s))\mathbf{i} + (\ln t + g(s))\mathbf{j} + (1/t +h(s))\mathbf{k}
$$
will contain your curve ($s=0$). By the way, three surfaces you have found are:

1. $f(s) = s$, $g(s) =0$, $h(s) = 0$
2. $f(s) = 0$, $g(s) =s$, $h(s) = 0$
3. $f(s) = 0$, $g(s) =0$, $h(s) = s$